# gnuplotで座標データから曲線を描く方法について

Tags: c, gnuplot

gnuplotに座標データを与え、曲線をプロットする方法を教えて下さい。
c言語で座標データを作成し、.datファイルに保存したものをgnuplotでグラフとして表示するプログラムを作成したいのですが、期待する曲線のプロットが出来ません。
以下はデータ作成のcコードです。

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){

FILE *data,*gp; 
char *data_file; 

int i, n=100; 

double r=3.80; // 初期条件
double x[101]; // 
x[0]=0.7; // 初期条件

/*--- データ作成 ---*/

data_file="sample.dat";
data=fopen(data_file,"w");
for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        x[i+1]=r*(1-x[i])*x[i];
        fprintf(data,"%lf\t%lf",x[i],x[i+1]);
}
fclose(data);

/*--- データをプロット ---*/

gp=popen("gnuplot -persist","w");
fprintf(gp,"set xrange [0:1]\n");
fprintf(gp,"set yrange [0:1]\n");
fprintf(gp,"plot \"%s\"with line\n",data_file);

fprintf(gp,"e\n");
pclose(gp);

return 0;
}
```

.dataファイルには100行2列で、1列目にはx座標、２列目にはy座標が出力されます。しかし、gnuplotで`plot "sample.dat" with lines`としても曲線にはなりません。何故なのでしょうか。[image: プロットされたもの]

以下はsample.datの中身の8行目までです。

```
0.700000 0.798000
0.798000 0.612545
0.612545 0.901868
0.901868 0.336308
0.336308 0.848179
0.848179 0.489331
0.489331 0.949567
0.949567 0.181979
```

Comment: 「.datファイル」の中身を書いてもらえば、回答が集まりやすそうです。

Comment: `fprintf(data,"%lf\t%lf",x[i],x[i+1]);` の部分ですが、これは`fprintf(data,"%lf\t%lf\n",x[i],x[i+1]);` が正しい（一行に数値が２個並ぶ）という事でよろしいでしょうか？

Comment: @htb アドバイスありがとうございます。　追記しておきました。

Comment: @metropolis datファイルのデータを追記しておきました。x座標、y座標というようにデータが２列に並んだものが100行あります。

Comment: 曲線にならないのはデータがソートされていないためで、`p '< sort -n sample.dat' w l` とすると良いかと。[こちら](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30445779/how-to-automatically-sort-the-x-values-in-gnuplot)が参考になるでしょう。

Comment: @metropolis それを参考にしたところ、曲線になりました。ありがとうございます。今回はx[n+1]=3.8x[i](1-x[i])という関数をプロットしたのですが、gnuplotでは差分方程式を座標などを用いずにシンプルにプロットする方法などはあるのでしょうか？

Comment: 一応、`x1=0.7` として、`plot sample [1:100] "+" using (x1):(x1=r*x1*(1-x1)) w l` とすればできますが、データは自動的にはソートされませんので、最初のプロット図と同じ結果になってしまいます。

Comment: [このディスカッションをチャットで続行](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84263/discussion-between-kat-and-metropolis)しましょう。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 今回は`x[n+1]=3.8x[i](1-x[i])`という関数をプロットしたのですが、gnuplotでは差分方程式を座標などを用いずにシンプルにプロットする方法などはあるのでしょうか？

条件次第では可能です。その条件というのは、データの X 値 が全て unique であることです。gnuplot には `smooth unique` というオプションがあって、これはデータを X 値でソートして、同一の X 値に対応する Y 値を平均化します。X 値が unique であれば、単に X 値でソートされるだけになります。

```
r = 3.80
x0 = 0.7
set xrange [0:1]
set yrange [0:1]
plot sample [i=1:100] '+' using (x1=(i==1?x0:x1)):(x1=r*x1*(1-x1)) with lines smooth unique
```